# keyup event on youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to create a demo app which plays a list of youtube videos. I added a feature which plays next/previous videos based on up/down arrow press. This works fine when the video isn't clicked. But it stops working when video is clicked.

```
  var video_list=[{'videoId':'abcd', 'videoId':'efgh'];
  var index = 0;
  $(document).on('keyup', function(event){
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if(keycode == '38') {
        if(index < video_list.length-1){
          index += 1;
        } else {
        index = 0;
        }
        player.loadVideoById({'videoId': video_list[index].videoId});
     }
    if (keycode == '40') { 
      if( index > 0) {
        index -= 1;
      } else {
        index = video_list.length-1;
      }

 player.loadVideoById({'videoId': video_list[index].videoId});
    }
});
```

Any idea how I can make the keyup event to trigger when video is focused?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    `document.activeElement`
to find out which element is focused, if it is the video tag (or whatever you are using) call the function that runs the video.

Comment: I get the warning 'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use 'KeyboardEvent.location' instead. and it looks like the iframe is getting focused

Comment: The code you provided doesn't contain anything about KeyboardEvent.keyLocation but I thibk it's something linked to e.which/e.keyCode, what do you mean by it's getting focused ?

Comment: Sorry. when try to print document.activeelement it returns the youtube iframe.

Comment: var videoTag = document.getElemengById('videoElement') and then check if document.activeElement == videoTag